# Perl hash : printing file columns based on key of another file

Tags: perl

I am new to perl and finding this difficult to deal with below situation and concept of hash in perl. I found some inputs to deal with this scenario but dont have Text:CSV module installed.

```
#/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warning;
use Data::Dumper;

my $INFILE_01 = "FILE_01.txt";
my $INFILE_02 = "FILE_02.txt";

open INFILE02, "< $INFILE_02" or die "$0 : Failed to open input file $INFILE_02 : $! \n";
```

> ```
> # Format of INFILE02 - Tab Delimited
> ```
>
> > ```
> > DEVELOMENT_TEST BUGID_TS57  TestID
> > DEVELOMENT_UAT  BUGID_TS57  TestID
> > DEVELOMENT_PROD BUGID_TS57  TestID
> > DEVELOMENT_REG  BUGID_TS57  TestID
> > DEVELOMENT_TEST BUGID_TS57  TestID
> > DEVELOMENT_TEST BUGID_TS57  TestID
> > DEVELOMENT_UAT  BUGID_TS57  TestID
> > ```

```
my %INFILE02;

while (my $line = <INFILE02>) {
    # Skipping if the line is empty or a comment
    next if ( $line =~ /^\s*$/ );
    next if ( $line =~ /^#\s*/ );
    chomo $line;

    if ($line = ~ /MOBILE_DEV/) { 
        my ($colum1, $column2, undef) = split /\t/, $line;
        $INFILE02{$colum1} = $colum2;
    }

}
close $INFILE02 or die "$0 : Failed to close input file $INFILE02 : $! \n";
print Dumper \%INFILE02;

# Output of %INFILE02
$VAR1 = {
        'DEVELOMENT_TEST' => 'BUGID_TS57',
        'DEVELOMENT_UAT'  => 'BUGID_TS57',
        'DEVELOMENT_PROD' => 'BUGID_TS57',
        'DEVELOMENT_REG'  => 'BUGID_TS57'
}
```

Now from above hash output of INFILE02 I need to match the keys DEVELOMENT_TEST,DEVELOMENT_UAT,  DEVELOMENT_PROD, DEVELOMENT_REG to File INFILE01 on each line one by one.

for Ex if Key DEVELOMENT_TEST is present on any line of INFILE01 then print the column1 , column 3 of INFILE01 and all columns of INFILE02 to a output file.

I need to repeat this for all the keys of %INFILE02.

> ```
> #Format of INFILE001 - Tab Delimited
> 119736    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_TEST
> 448094    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_TEST
> 206893    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_TEST
> 333743    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_TEST
> 172534    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_PROD
> 785275    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_PROD
> 995932    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_PROD
> 223488    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_TEST
> 433512    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_TEST
> 640802    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_PROD
> 403866    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_UAT
> 828788    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_UAT
> 751490    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_UAT
> 972562    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_UAT
> 367541    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_REG
> 481360    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_REG
> 920232    PRODUCTTESTING  DEVELOMENT_UAT
> ```

Desired output should be as below:

```
119736  DEVELOMENT_TEST BUGID_TS57  TestID
448094  DEVELOMENT_TEST BUGID_TS57  TestID
206893  DEVELOMENT_TEST BUGID_TS57  TestID
333743  DEVELOMENT_TEST BUGID_TS57  TestID
223488  DEVELOMENT_TEST BUGID_TS57  TestID
433512  DEVELOMENT_TEST BUGID_TS57  TestID
172534  DEVELOMENT_PROD BUGID_TS57  TestID
785275  DEVELOMENT_PROD BUGID_TS57  TestID
995932  DEVELOMENT_PROD BUGID_TS57  TestID
640802  DEVELOMENT_PROD BUGID_TS57  TestID
403866  DEVELOMENT_UAT  BUGID_TS57  TestID
828788  DEVELOMENT_UAT  BUGID_TS57  TestID
751490  DEVELOMENT_UAT  BUGID_TS57  TestID
972562  DEVELOMENT_UAT  BUGID_TS57  TestID
920232  DEVELOMENT_UAT  BUGID_TS57  TestID
367541  DEVELOMENT_REG  BUGID_TS57  TestID
481360  DEVELOMENT_REG  BUGID_TS57  TestID
```

Please advice on same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not getting the concept of comparing my keys to the values of another file.

Comment: Please, edit your question to be more clear. The code makes no sense in relation to your data, for example i see nowhere in the data the hardcoded `MOBILE_DEV` string. Also, the `chomo` should be `chomp`. etc..

Answer (score 0):

Something like below where first argument is file one, and second argument is file two :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %hash=undef;
open(my $fh,$ARGV[0]);
while (<$fh>) {
    my @fields=split(/\s+/);
    $hash{$fields[0]}=1;
}
close($fh);

open(my $fh,$ARGV[1]);
while (<$fh>) {
    for my $key (keys %hash) {
        if ($key && /$key/) {
            print "$_";
        }
    }
}
close($fh);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `my %hash=undef` doesn't do what you think it does. Adding `use warnings` to the code would have shown you the problem.